# show/hide some menus depend on the Sonata admin ROLE

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, symfony-2.3, symfony-sonata

I'm working on a web project using Symfony2 , and i used Sonata Admin for the admin Panel , every thing works fine but what i want to do is ,on the dashboard menus of sonata Admin , i need to show hide some menus depend on the admin ROLE , so did any one do this before or know how to do it ?
i tryed to use the config of the roles but when i'm connecting with a ROlE diffrent of ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN the top menu dont show up ,

```
- { path: ^/admin, role: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN,ROLE_ADMIN_NEWS] }
```

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i found the solution for this i need just to define the groups on the config.yml Like this

```
dashboard:
    groups:
        Content:
            label: Content
            items:
                - sonata.admin.pages
                - sonata.admin.menus
            roles: [ ROLE_ADMIN_CONTENT, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN ]
```

Comment: Hello Gm, I try to implement same thing but it not working for me so please explain me like dashboard is service name or any other thing becuase I think name issue