# Hiding Sonata Admin Menu Elements By Role

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I have read widely and tried examples but still cannot get the hang of Symfony2 ROLEs and Sonata Admin. I have four levels of users,

- SuperAdmin which is basically me the developer
- Admin who is the application owner. He has access to everything except user/ group management. Admin adds an Agency who will get an email with credentials into system
- Agency who then adds the exployees of people(Facilitators) working for the project
- Facilitators who are Agency employees who enter field Entries into the system

I want in Sonata Admin, to:

- Facilitators to only see Entry management menu
- Agency to see Entry and Facilitator Management menus only
- Admin to see Agency,Entry and Facilitator management menus only
- SuperAdmin to see everything else including user and Group management generated by SonataUserBundle

Here is how my security.yml file looks like

```
security:
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_FACILITATOR:   
        -   ROLE_USER
        -   ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN
        -   ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_ENTRY_EDIT
        -   ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_ENTRY_LIST
        -   ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_ENTRY_CREATE
        -   ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_ENTRY_VIEW
        -   ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_ENTRY_DELETE
    ROLE_AGENCY:
        -   ROLE_FACILITATOR
        -   ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_FACILITATOR_EDIT
        -   ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_FACILITATOR_LIST
        -   ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_FACILITATOR_CREATE
        -   ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_FACILITATOR_VIEW
        -   ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_FACILITATOR_DELETE
    ROLE_OLX_ADMIN:
        -   ROLE_AGENCY
        -   ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN
        -   ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_AGENCY_EDIT
        -   ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_AGENCY_LIST
        -   ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_AGENCY_CREATE
        -   ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_AGENCY_VIEW
        -   ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_AGENCY_DELETE
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: 
        -   ROLE_OLX_ADMIN
        -   ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCHS
```

Comment: just inject the security context in your menu class then you can use `$context->isGranted('ROLE_USER')`

Comment: The menus are dynamically generated by sonata

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336623/show-hide-some-menus-depend-on-the-sonata-admin-role